# Finding a users friends and determining if they have the app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-opengraph

So, after looking around the two solutions ive seen are:

**1) Using the graph API**

```
me/friends?fields=installed
```

**2) Using FQL**

```
SELECT uid FROM user WHERE uid in (SELECT uid1 FROM friend WHERE uid2=me()) AND is_app_user
SELECT uid FROM user WHERE uid in (SELECT uid1 FROM friend WHERE uid2=me()) AND NOT is_app_user
```

Using the graph API i'm always met with permissions issues and cannot find what permission i need to request in order to access it. And the FQL solution seems to always return false.

So I'm left wondering if theres something simple that im missing in order to get this working,or whether or not these methods are outdated and theres a better way.

Thanks in advance

**EDIT 1**

I should mention that i am working from a C# api

Answer (score 1):

Using PHP SDK you can get the friendlist by using:

```
$facebook->api(array('method' => 'friends.getAppUsers'));
```

Comment: Ah, well that would be the ticket. But I dont have access to the PHP sdk from within c# :(

Answer (score 0):

As for the permissions: You need to have the email permission to get the friends list with installed flag in it.

I can guess that you are following the normal login flow. like, 
1)opening session
2)requesting read permissions (user_info etc.)
 just add the "email" permission in read permissions as well and you shall get this installed flag.

3) and then you can use either the graph api or FQL, results should be similar.